# FileNotFoundException while running docker image

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

I have configured a Firebase properties file as follows -

```
@Bean
Firestore firestore() throws IOException {
    InputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("my-karwaan-firebase-adminsdk.json");
    GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount);
```

JSON file is present under the resources folder.

Everything works fine on the localhost. 
But on docker it's throwing while running docker image

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate 
[com.google.cloud.firestore.Firestore]: Factory method 'firestore' threw exception; nested
 exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: my-karwaan-firebase-adminsdk.json
```

Docker file content as follows -

```
# Build Jar File
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-8-slim as stage1
WORKDIR /home/app
COPY . /home/app
RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml clean package

# Create an Image
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
EXPOSE 8080
COPY --from=stage1 /home/app/target/myapp.jar myapp.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "myapp.jar"]
```

I tried to give an absolute path but it's not working on docker.

Directory structure as follows - 
[image]

Comment: The only file you're copying into the result image is the jar file.  One of Docker's key features is filesystem isolation: unless you go out of your way to configure it, containers can't see or access files on the host system (or vice versa).

Comment: What is the best way here to provide configuration?

Comment: What is the location of your `dockerfile` ??

Comment: @DupinderSingh In project directory

Comment: means root location Am i right ?

Comment: @NagendraNigade I updated the answer, please have a look, if any problem please let me know, I am here

Answer (score 1):

See the basic problem in your `dockerfile` is

You are setting `WORKDIR` then while `COPY` you said `COPY` in `/home/app` so if you set `WORKDIR` then it means Any `RUN`, `CMD`, `ADD`, `COPY`, or `ENTRYPOINT` command will be executed in the specified working directory.

[image]

So to avoid the confusions try as following

```
# Build Jar File
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-8-slim as stage1
WORKDIR /home/app
#COPY FROM PROJECT ROOT DIR TO WORKING ROOT DIR i.e: /home/app 
COPY . .
RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml clean package

# Create an Image
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
EXPOSE 8080
COPY --from=stage1 /home/app/target/myapp.jar myapp.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "myapp.jar"]
```

Try this :)

PS:
Once you start the container please do `exec` and check is all the project details are at right directory or not and `mvn build` is building jar with correct name or not